# Is there any way to add a Twitter share button to the Slack API payload in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, twitter, slack-api

I would like to add a share button for social media. I've got the Slack workflow buttons working, but I'd like those receiving the message payload to be able to share what they're receiving. Here's what I've got so far.

```
def post_summary_to_slack(self):
    data = str(
        {'text': self.summary_printout,
            'attachments': [
                {
                    "fallback": "Was this a good use of time and money?",
                    "title": "Was this a good use of time and money?",
                    "callback_id": "meetings_survey",
                    "color": "#800080",
                    "attachment_type": "default",
                    "actions": [
                        {
                            "name": "yes",
                            "text": "Yes",
                            "type": "button",
                            "value": "yes"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "no",
                            "text": "No",
                            "type": "button",
                            "value": "no"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "maybe",
                            "text": "I'm Not Sure",
                            "type": "button",
                            "value": "maybe"
                        },
                        /* maybe here:*/
                        {
                            "name": "twitter",
                            "text": "Tweet",
                            "type": "button",
                            "value": "Here are the results from the latest analysis"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    )
    url = self.SLACK_HOOK
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    f.close()
```

Has anybody tried something like this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do that. However, Slack does not provide a Twitter share button out-of-the-box, so your script will need to implement that functionality. So your Twitter share button will call your script (like any other message button) and your script will need to forward the message contents to Twitter by calling the correct [Twitter APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api) etc.